# Distributing turtles at a patch

Tags: netlogo

In the image below, the black box represents a patch. I wish to create agents of size- 
(Patch-size/8)

and distribute them at the top of the patch as such.

Also, possible to to create a code such that it takes :

Patch-Size as input and distributes them accordingly.

*Previous Code Used:*
My previous approach sprout at the centre and moves them to align with the desired positions but it is considerably length and not effective if I wish to variate number of agents.

`

[image]

Comment: Please explain the downvote. I am new to NetLogo. Sorry if the question is trivial.

Comment: Because of the use of patch-size normally it makes no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so, forget about patch-size for a moment, as we are going to be working with unit patches, without regard to the number of pixels.

I'm assuming the number of turtles is variable, and that we want the turtles to fit exactly inside the width of the patch, and with the tops of the turtles aligned with the top edge of the patch.

If the number of turtles is constant, or the maximum number is constant, and/or the size is constant, then the code can be a little more simple, as we can avoid recalculating some things.

Anyway, for C turtles:

- The gap between the turtles is `1 / C`
- The "half-gap" is also useful, that's `gap / 2`
- This is also the size of the turtles
- Hence, the turtles will definitely just fit across the patch
- The ycor of the turtles will be `pxyor + .5 - half-gap`

  - Since gap is the size, this puts the turtles along the top
- The xcor will be `pxcor - .5 + gap * N - half-gap`

  N is the number of the current turtle. So, the xcor varies from a half-gap from the left edge to a half-gap from the right edge.

  Here, `pxcor - .5` shifts the turtle center all the way to the left edge

  Then, `+ gap * N` shifts the turtle over N turtle widths,

  Then, `- half-gap` shifts the turtle back one half turtle size.

  This makes sure the first and last turtles are just touching the edge.

So, let's do it:

```
to align-inside-at-top ;; patch procedure
   let counter count turtles-here ;; we will use this as a count-down, after using it in some calculations
   if counter > 0                 ;; could assume there are turtles, but we are not.
   [ let gap 1 / counter          ;; size of turtles, gap between turtles
     let half-gap gap / 2         ;; half-size of turtles
     let ytop  pycor + .5 - half-gap
     let xleft pxcor - .5 - half-gap
     ask turtles-here
     [ set size gap
       set ycor ytop
       set xcor xleft + gap * counter
       set counter counter - 1    ;; so we're placing them from right to left
     ]
   ]
end
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. It works great. If I had to align them to say right or left. How do you think the code would change?

Comment: Thanks. It works great. If I had to align them to say right or left. How do you think the code would change? I have tried it, but don't seem to get the logic correct.

Answer (score 2):

keep in mind no matter the patch-size patches are always 1 step across.

( pxcor - .5, pxcor + .5) X (pycor - .5, pycor +.5)

Patch-size is a sort of zoom it doesn't normally effect a simulation.

With that said and assuming you are doing this as some sort of demonstration or visualization. Anything you do for aesthetics tends to slow things down but here you go.

```
To line-up

    Let c count turtles-here
    Ask turtles-here
       [
       Set ycor pycor - .45
       Set xcor pxcor + .45 - c / patch-size
       Let c c - 1
       ]
     End
```

If turtles on a patch > patch size it will mess up.

Comment: What role do you think `patch-size` is playing here? I agree with your advice not to use it at all, but then your code uses it.

Comment: I assume he is using it for a visualization or something. I was capitulating to his desire. But yeah simulation wise patch-size is meaningless. It is simply a way to scale the view. It should have been call view-scale.

Comment: But even when doing something purely for visualization, when would you ever want the patch size to enter into a position calculation? Wouldn't you always want the same appearance regardless of scale?

Comment: In nearly all cases yes. Begrudgingly i will play devil's advocate. Wishing I had your side to argue. One that springs to mind is very small turtles become invisible at different patch-sizes. One could correct for that?  But even using netlogo for purely artistic endeavors I don't see much call for changing patch size. I wish the OP would give his reasons.

Comment: Good point about wanting to handle very small patch sizes specially. I can see that coming up.

Comment: I personally don't see a reason I would ever use set-patch-size. ... a dramatic zoom?

Comment: Usually you'd be doing `resize-world` and `set-patch-size` together, rather than doing the latter by itself. And you need both in order to keep the view about the same size overall.

Comment: Ifelse mouse-inside? [Set-patch-size 15   ask turtles[set size .2]][set-patch-size 2 ask turtles[set size 1]]

Comment: Using patch-size as you are here doesn't make sense. You also fail to set the size, which should probably be set, unless the turtles are already small enough.

Comment: Firstly it is a joke and secondly the states of mouse-inside? form a partition the turtle sizes are .2 when the mouse is inside the view 1 when it is outside. the code makes an exploding view. Works fine.